# What is the name of the trilogy in which an A.I. Space Station goes renegade?

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, space-station

I read the first (of what was supposed to be a trilogy) in which an A.I. was built on a space station so that they could shut it down it in case it went out of control.  Of course, it cannot be contained, and at the end of the first book it has started an attack from one end of the space station (the computer/factory end) against the humans in the other end.  I have lost the book and never saw either of the sequels.  Do you know the name of the books?  It is likely from the 80s or 90s.

Comment: There was an oldie called "the two faces of tomorrow " with a similar plot but I don't know if it was part of a trilogy (I think I read it before the 80's) . author's name escapes me

Comment: @Danny3414 That author's name is James P. Hogan and he might have written a 2nd book but not trilogy. Well worth reading any of his work if you like a solid dose of science in your fiction.

Comment: @Verdan the OP says it was INTENDED to be the start of a trilogy. Long time since I read it. I just wonder if maybe the blurb on the copy that this  OP read stated "book one" but then the author didn't go back to that story.  Details online seem to match the memory but this smartphone of mine is very cruddy for copy/paste

Comment: I only recall the one book which does sound like "Two Faces of Tomorrow" by James P. Hogan.